# How to compile/update github java file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github, jar

There is a working jar file on Github version 1.4 (https://github.com/ggodlewski/smux-anki-converter/downloads)

The original author has updated the code to versions: 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 but they are not standalone working jar files but mere zip files containing:

.classpath,

.gitignore,

.project

pom.xml

and some of the folders contained in the working version 1.4.
Version 1.4 is about 7MB and the updates are only about 45kB each.

The project itself seems to be dead and I cannot get in touch with the author.

My question is: how do I make those updates work? How to update version 1.4 to 1.7 on my PC?

I have tried to figure it out using Eclipse import/export but I am not a programmer and I just don't know how to do it.

Please help.

Comment: Um, what? https://github.com/ggodlewski/smux-anki-converter there are lots more files, including a folder src containing all the source files.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this immibis. I apologise but I am not a programmer and I'm a bit struggling with all this. Ideally, I would like to get version 1.7 of smux-anki-converter. It seems to be available at https://github.com/ggodlewski/smux-anki-converter/releases  but not as a standalone working jar file. I guess it hasn't been compiled. Only versions 1.1 -1.4 seem to be complete working versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build from source as follows:

1. Make sure that you have a Java JDK installed.  Java 6 or later is required, but I would advise Java 7 or Java 8.
2. Make sure you have Maven installed and configured.  (If you need to use an HTTP proxy to access the internet, you will need to instruct Maven ...)
3. Use `git clone <url>` to create a clean sandbox.
4. Change directory to the sandbox.
5. Run `mvn assembly:assembly` to build.  (That is what the README file says ...)

   The first time you do this, Maven is probably going to download a lot of stuff from the Maven Central repo.
6. If it works, the built JAR(s) will be somewhere in the `target` subdirectory.

(Note: I haven't tried this myself.  YMMV.)